# React Select Value passing to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a Select tag which has default options in it :

Screen shot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/T85LV.png

so i have options listed here :

```
  const options = [
  { value: 'All categories', label: 'All categories' },
  { value: 'Basic', label: 'Basic' },
  { value: 'Premium', label: 'Premium' },
]
```

The filter function which is used to differentiate the ntf's :

```
async function filterCategory(cat) {
        var filterCat = [];
        setshowlist(false);
        if (cat !== "all") {
          filterCat = allTokens.filter(function (el) {
            if (connected) {
              return (
                el.tokendetails.tokenCategory === cat &&
                el.tokendetails.networkVersion ===
                providerChainID.toString()
              );
            } else {
              return el.tokendetails.tokenCategory === cat;         
            }
          });
          setexploreTokens(filterCat);
        } else {
          if (connected)  {
            filterCat = allTokens.filter(function (el) {
              return (
                el.tokendetails.networkVersion ===
                providerChainID.toString()
              );
            });
          } else {
            filterCat = allTokens;
            
          }
        }
        setexploreTokens(filterCat);
        setshowlist(true);
      }
```

And the Select Dropdown part where i need to pass All categories or Basic or Premium from what i select :

```
<div className='dropdownSelect one'>
  <Select className='select1' styles={customStyles} menuContainerStyle={{'zIndex': 999}} 
   defaultValue={options[0]} options={options} onClick={filterCategory({options})}/>
</div>
```

The issue i am facing is on how to pass either "All Categories " , "Basic" , "Premium" from Select tag to that function filtercat and can filter the nfts ? can anyone guide me thru that !
Appreciate for your help !

Comment: onChange={(e) => filterCategory(e.target.value)}

Comment: i get this if i do that @CptSosen 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Comment: Which lib you are using? It seems like e.target.value is empty

Comment: import Select from 'react-select'
@CptSosen 
also its functional component

Comment: ok i think i got it , i used onChange={(e) => filterCategory(e.value)} and its working !

Comment: Can you try this? onChange={(_e, newValue ) => filterCategory(newValue)}. I read doc and i'm courious if it will work

Comment: this isnt working , when i checked console it gives me this : https://imgur.com/a/fLHyFVH
@cptsosen